# Restkit Testing Managed Object Requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

Does somebody know, how a managed object request (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation) can be tested in Restkit? Normal Request Operations are easy to test as described here https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Unit-Testing-with-RestKit#testing-object-request-operations

Comment: What have you tried? Did you supply the MOC and cache? MOC is required, cache is optional.

Comment: I supply the MOC form the RKTestFactory. Create a RKManagedObjectRequestOperation over the RKObjectManager from the RKTestFactory and start this the same way as in the "Testing tutorial" (e.g synchronous: start, waitUntil...) but it never comes to an end. any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Tests/Logic/Network/RKManagedObjectRequestOperationTest.m?source=cc

Comment: I'm doing nearly the same. My problem is now that when the test reaches `[managedObjectRequestOperation isFinished]` it is FALSE. But I'm not using expecta. Is that the problem?

Comment: With higher loglevels: the console log output stops after Finished performing object mapping. Results: {
    "<null>" = "<Activity: 0x1157b100> (entity: Activity; id: 0x97c0cf0 <x-coredata:///Activity/t6344D8F7-4F86-401B-B...